# Jquery Pegar Valor Checkbox Mais Próximo por Linha

Tags: jquery, asp.net, mvc, checkbox

Preciso de ajuda com o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou querendo pegar o checkbox que está desabilitado e jogar no console 0 para o que está desabilitado, e 1 para o que está habilitado.

Meu fonte está assim: (asp.net mvc)

```
@model IEnumerable<Apontamento.Models.Modulos>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Acesso";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
}

<h2>Acesso</h2>
<br />
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.cod_modulo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nome_modulo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.usuario)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.permissao)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr class="linha" data-codigo_modulo="@item.cod_modulo" data-usuario="@item.usuario">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cod_modulo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nome_modulo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.usuario)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.permissao)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".linha").each(function () {
            var codigo_modulo = $(this).data("codigo_modulo");
            var usuario = $(this).data("usuario");
            var valor_atual = 0;
            if ($(this).next("input").has("checked")) {
                valor_atual = 1;
            } else {
                valor_atual = 0;
            }
            console.log(codigo_modulo + " " + usuario + " " + valor_atual);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Estou com dúvida nesse jquery aqui:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".linha").each(function () {
            var codigo_modulo = $(this).data("codigo_modulo");
            var usuario = $(this).data("usuario");
            var valor_atual = 0;
            if ($(this).next("input").has("checked")) {
                valor_atual = 1;
            } else {
                valor_atual = 0;
            }
            console.log(codigo_modulo + " " + usuario + " " + valor_atual);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Eu mando jogar pro console, mas ele joga assim (1 para tudo)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu fiz um `$(".linha").each(function () {` pra percorrer cada linha, o código do modulo e o nome está pegando certo, porém essa condição não está funcionando:

```
var valor_atual = 0;
if ($(this).next("input").has("checked")) {
    valor_atual = 1;
} else {
    valor_atual = 0;
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a como testar se o checkbox da linha está checkado ou não?

Se ajudar, o fonte da página fica assim: (na tabela)(perceba que o segundo input não está com o `checked="checked"`

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>
            C&#243;digo Modulo
        </th>
        <th>
            Nome do M&#243;dulo
        </th>
        <th>
            usuario
        </th>
        <th>
            permissao
        </th>
    </tr>

        <tr class="linha" data-codigo_modulo="1" data-usuario="dayane.fiedler">
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                Produtos
            </td>
            <td>
                dayane.fiedler
            </td>
            <td>
                <input checked="checked" class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo permissao é obrigatório." id="item_permissao" name="item.permissao" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="item.permissao" type="hidden" value="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="linha" data-codigo_modulo="2" data-usuario="dayane.fiedler">
            <td>
                2
            </td>
            <td>
                Usu&#225;rios
            </td>
            <td>
                dayane.fiedler
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo permissao é obrigatório." id="item_permissao" name="item.permissao" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="item.permissao" type="hidden" value="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="linha" data-codigo_modulo="3" data-usuario="dayane.fiedler">
            <td>
                3
            </td>
            <td>
                Ordem Produ&#231;&#227;o
            </td>
            <td>
                dayane.fiedler
            </td>
            <td>
                <input checked="checked" class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo permissao é obrigatório." id="item_permissao" name="item.permissao" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="item.permissao" type="hidden" value="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="linha" data-codigo_modulo="5" data-usuario="dayane.fiedler">
            <td>
                5
            </td>
            <td>
                Adminstrador
            </td>
            <td>
                dayane.fiedler
            </td>
            <td>
                <input checked="checked" class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo permissao é obrigatório." id="item_permissao" name="item.permissao" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="item.permissao" type="hidden" value="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="linha" data-codigo_modulo="6" data-usuario="dayane.fiedler">
            <td>
                6
            </td>
            <td>
                Opera&#231;&#245;es
            </td>
            <td>
                dayane.fiedler
            </td>
            <td>
                <input checked="checked" class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo permissao é obrigatório." id="item_permissao" name="item.permissao" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="item.permissao" type="hidden" value="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está fazendo errado ao buscar o `input`. O `.next()` irá selecionar o próximo elemento do seletor e não *buscar* o input.

Basta trocar o `if` por isto:

```
if ($(this).find("input").is(":checked")) {
```

O `.find()` busca o elemento dentro do seletor e o `.is(":checked")` verifica se está checado.

**Veja:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".linha").each(function () {
            var codigo_modulo = $(this).data("codigo_modulo");
            var usuario = $(this).data("usuario");
            var valor_atual = 0;
            if ($(this).find("input").is(":checked")) {
                valor_atual = 1;
            } else {
                valor_atual = 0;
            }
            console.log(codigo_modulo + " " + usuario + " " + valor_atual);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>
            C&#243;digo Modulo
        </th>
        <th>
            Nome do M&#243;dulo
        </th>
        <th>
            usuario
        </th>
        <th>
            permissao
        </th>
    </tr>

        <tr class="linha" data-codigo_modulo="1" data-usuario="dayane.fiedler">
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                Produtos
            </td>
            <td>
                dayane.fiedler
            </td>
            <td>
                <input checked="checked" class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo permissao é obrigatório." id="item_permissao" name="item.permissao" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="item.permissao" type="hidden" value="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="linha" data-codigo_modulo="2" data-usuario="dayane.fiedler">
            <td>
                2
            </td>
            <td>
                Usu&#225;rios
            </td>
            <td>
                dayane.fiedler
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo permissao é obrigatório." id="item_permissao" name="item.permissao" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="item.permissao" type="hidden" value="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="linha" data-codigo_modulo="3" data-usuario="dayane.fiedler">
            <td>
                3
            </td>
            <td>
                Ordem Produ&#231;&#227;o
            </td>
            <td>
                dayane.fiedler
            </td>
            <td>
                <input checked="checked" class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo permissao é obrigatório." id="item_permissao" name="item.permissao" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="item.permissao" type="hidden" value="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="linha" data-codigo_modulo="5" data-usuario="dayane.fiedler">
            <td>
                5
            </td>
            <td>
                Adminstrador
            </td>
            <td>
                dayane.fiedler
            </td>
            <td>
                <input checked="checked" class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo permissao é obrigatório." id="item_permissao" name="item.permissao" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="item.permissao" type="hidden" value="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="linha" data-codigo_modulo="6" data-usuario="dayane.fiedler">
            <td>
                6
            </td>
            <td>
                Opera&#231;&#245;es
            </td>
            <td>
                dayane.fiedler
            </td>
            <td>
                <input checked="checked" class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo permissao é obrigatório." id="item_permissao" name="item.permissao" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="item.permissao" type="hidden" value="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

> **Nota:** Não repita o `id` `item_permissao`. Um `id` deve ser único na página.

Comment: Caraaaa muuuuuuuito obrigado!! Me ajudou muito... estou iniciando agora no jquery e buguei pra fazer isso aushuashuas.. muitíssimo obrigado!!

Comment: Blz! Só não repita `id` por que é errado.

Comment: Blz... Vlw cara!

Comment: Adicionei no Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/putomb3d/18/ , agora colocando na classe no `td` e pegando o valor do td... ai não repete o id :) E adicionei um botão, clicando no botão mostra no console o que está com check e o que não. Muito obrigado por me mostrar essa função `find()`